# Asp.Net Display message instead of loading image for long running process

Tags: asp.net

When i click on button need to display message instead of loading image for long running process.Need to show what is happening in my code behind.Like below stages

1. Collecting information from database..........
2. Generating PDF document..............
3. Sending e-Mail........
4. Done.

Note:No need to set default time for stages it need to take message from code behind and display.
Please send me any related links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Easy incremental status updates for long requests](http://encosia.com/easy-incremental-status-updates-for-long-requests/)

Answer (score -2):

You could easily add a TextBox control and change the Text property by your code behind, in function of what you do.

For example:

```
private void Loading()
{
  txtLoading.Text = "stage1.Collecting information from database";

  // PUT CODE TO COLLECT INFORMATION FROM DATABASE HERE

  txtLoading.Text += "\r\nstage2.Generating PDF document";

  // PUT CODE TO GENERATE PDF DOCUMENT HERE

  // ETC ETC
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think you missed the ASP.Net tag.

Comment: So the user will wait till server finishes and than he will see all updates at once ?